# How can you do a full outer join in sqlserver 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, join

How can you do a full outer join in sqlserver 2005?

Seems like there is full outer join in sqlserver 2008 but I need to do this in sqlserver 2005.

In other words, I am merging two views based on the ACCTNUM col in both views (The views show aggregates so there is at most one ACCTNUM record in each view for each account)  and I would like every record in each table to show up, even when there is no match in the other (ie, full outer join).

Comment: FULL JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN  are supported in 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 supports full joins:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(SQL.90).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(SQL.90).aspx

In fact, I think FULL JOIN works at *least* as far back SQL Server 7.

Answer (score 4):

This will work in SQL 2005

```
Select
    tableA.Column,
    tableA.AnotherColumn,
    tableB.Column
From
    tableA
Full Outer Join
    tableB On tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

Note you can use `Full Join` or `Full Outer Join`, it doesnt make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Full outer joins should be [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(SQL.90).aspx) by SQL Server 2005 - what makes you think they aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are using Access to connect to a DB, you can't use full outer join, since Access does not support it.

Comment: ..except for pass-through queries or ADPs where it's run on the SQL box and not in JET

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM TABLE1 A FULL JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.Id = B.TableAID
```